# In this Cumulative Distribution Function, am I finding the wrong term?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, uniform-integrability

Question I was given: Let V be a uniform random variable distributed over the interval (0,1). Let $\ X = \frac{1}{\sqrt(U)}$. What is the cumulative distribution function and probability density function of X?

I understand the basic concept here behind cumulative distribution functions and probability density functions. What's throwing me off here is the additional parameter saying that V is a uniform random variable.

Is the cumulative distance function just:
$\ \int\limits_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt(V)}dV $ which would then just equal 2?

Then the prob dens function would be:
$$
    \frac{1}{\sqrt(V)}-----0<V<1
$$
$$
    0------otherwise
$$
This seems too simple to me to be the correct answer though.
Am I missing something? Am I finding the cumulative distance function of V rather than of X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We find the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ of $X$. So we want to find $\Pr(X\le x)$.

If $x\le 1$, then $F_X(x)=0$.  For since $0\lt U\lt 1$, it is **impossible** for $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{U}}$ to be $\le 1$.

Now we find $F_X(x)$ for $x\gt 1$.

We have $X\le x$ if and only if $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{U}}\le x$. Flip it over. So $X\le x$ if and omly if $\sqrt{U}\ge \dfrac{1}{x}$, that is, if and only if $U\ge \dfrac{1}{x^2}$.

But $\Pr\left(U\ge \dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)=1-\Pr\left(U\le \dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$. Since $U$ is uniform, this is simply $1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$. Thus for $X\gt 1$,
$$F_X(x)= 1-\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

For the density function $f_X(x)$, differentiate the cdf.

Comment: Which would just yield 2/X^3 for X>1 and 0 otherwise?

Comment: And thank you - that clarification was fantastic!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, the density function (for $x\gt 1$) is $\frac{2}{x^3}$.